# Ubuntu no longer booting and is in a restart loop after using "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade"

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and I want to update to 20.04. So I was trying to update my ubuntu using the following commands before I upgrade it using the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and now it won't boot. It just gets to the setup page before shutting down and starting back up. It is stuck in this loop and won't progress.

Why is it doing this and how can I sort it? Do I need to just return to my backup?

Comment: Hmm I wonder how this in itself could result in bootloop? On Ubuntu, `apt-get dist-upgrade` does not actually upgrade the distribution unless you also change the repos.

Comment: It is my understanding that on Ubuntu, the preferred method is by using `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @ArturMeinild I did use ``` sudo do-release-upgrade ``` but it asked me to do all updates, so I looked up the issue, which seemed to come up a lot in 16.04, and it said to do the commands in my question before doing the do-release-upgrade.

Comment: Yes ok, and that's what I find odd. In your situation, I would try restoring to backup, and then maybe try again without the `dist-upgrade` part. It sounds like it's another program dependency that causes the bootloop before you even get to the Ubuntu release upgrade part.